# How to get all capabilities

Tags: capabilities

how to get all capabilities regardless of user roles? so far I am only seeing tutorial of how to get capabilities per user. I want to list all available capabilities in one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create `[all-capabilities]` shortcode. Put this code in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_all_capabilities() {
    $out = '<style>
.flex-columns {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 3em;
    column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}        
</style>';
    $out .= '<p class="flex-columns">';
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        if ( $user->caps['administrator'] ) {
            $allcaps = array_keys( $user->allcaps );
            foreach ( $allcaps as $cap ) {
                $out .= $cap . '<br>';
            }
            $out .= '</p>';
            return $out;
        }
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'all-capabilities', 'wpse_all_capabilities' );
```

**Update**: it is possible that `Administrator` has some capabilities removed, so we need to scan all users. Modified code follows:

```
function wpse_all_capabilities() {
    $allcaps = array();
    $out = '<style>
.flex-columns {
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3em;
    column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    column-span: all;
}        
</style>';
    $out .= '<div class="flex-columns">';
    $out .= "<h2>All Possible Users' Capabilities<hr></h2><p>";
    $users = get_users();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $caps = array_keys( $user->allcaps );
        foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
            if ( !in_array( $cap, $allcaps, true ) ) {
                $num = array_push( $allcaps, $cap );  
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ( $allcaps as $capability ) {
        $out .= $capability . '<br>';
    }
    $out .= '</p></div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode( 'all-capabilities', 'wpse_all_capabilities' );
```

Now, you can use `[all-capabilities]` shortcode on your page.

Comment: Hi Frank, it does the job. but looks like its not picking up my custom capabilities

Comment: nevermind. i just have to get the capabilities from both user and roles.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a single function you can call to get an array of all the capabilities. However, you can easily grab all admin capabilities, like this:

```
$caps = get_role( 'administrator' )->capabilities;
```

If, for some reason, there are capabilities that are available to other user roles but not admins, then you could loop over all the user roles like this:

```
foreach( wp_roles()->role_objects as $role ) {...}
```

There might be a dozen user roles or more, depending on the site and its plugins, but this will be way faster than looping over all the users, which could be thousands.